# Python 1d Fourier Transform in wavenumber domain?

Tags: python, fft, chemistry

I'd like to do 1d fft on my 2d spectrum (i.e. fft along time axis at y=101,102 ... 399,400)
[image: 2d spectrum]

The one of fft spectrum (simply by 'np.fft.fft(signal) / len(signal)') shows x axis maybe in Hz.
But my time axis is fs scale (10^-15 s).
[image: 1d fft spectrum]

1. Can I use fs scale?
2. If so, how can I convert Hz to cm^-1 unit?